# User Synchronizing

Tags: debian, password, authentication, synchronization

Is there any possible way to synchronize my main server's `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/gshadow` and `/etc/group`?

I have 1000+ users and it's a hassle to loop `userdel` and loop `useradd`.

I tried placing those files in my personal storage and using `wget` to fetch. Replacing the contents of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` is possible but when it comes with `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/shadow` it shows blank and corrupted my system.

As much as possible I don't want to use LDAP or any other third parties. I tried searching for tutorials for LDAP using Debian 9 but it shows old tutorials and I can't even figure out how it works. What I know is I need to `adduser` to the system first before I can authenticate to my slave servers.

I'm using `watch` command to execute a shell script which contains `wget` commands to replace the four files.

Comment: rsync for synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set up **Ansible[1]** to get those files synchronized between the *master* and the *nodes*.  I've been learning *Ansible* lately so I'm just applying what I've learnt so far.

Say you have *master*, and *node_1*..*node_n* and *master* has the latest files.

Of course, you'll need to install *Ansible* on your *master* as well being able to ssh to the nodes via the *master*.

First, create a hosts file, say *ansible_hosts* like so:
[using ellipses to denote that you can add how many nodes you like,
and use your own host names]

```
[sync_nodes]
node_1.example.local
node_2.example.local
...
```

Then create a file called, say *sync_pw.yml*, like:

```
---
 - hosts: sync_nodes
   tasks:
     - name: Copy file from master to {{ item }}
       include_tasks: copy_tasks.yml
       with_items:
         - "{{ groups['sync_nodes'] }}"
```

Then in copy_tasks.yml:

```
---
 - name: Copy /etc/passwd
   copy: src=/etc/passwd dest=/etc/passwd

 - name: Copy /etc/passwd
   copy: src=/etc/group dest=/etc/groups
```

then in the command prompt:

```
  ansible-playbook -i ansible_hosts ./sync_pw.yml
```

To note:

1. You need sudo perms on all nodes.  [got bit by the MODULE FAILURE error]
2. python needs to exist on remote.

[1] - https://www.ansible.com/community